# How do I stop my thread and will my service stop too if I do?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm currently working on my first android app and I've run into a problem.

My app is supposed to be counting in the background using a Service and I'm creating a new thread to handle that. If I don't stop the thread in my Service's onDestroy() method, my phone gives me the message "Unfortunately, (my app) has stopped." every time I close the app. I need to stop it somehow, and I tried to do it using :

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){  
      **my code**
}:
```

And then interrupting it in the onDestroy() method. 
It works, but it makes my app count extremely fast, so I would like to know if it can be done any other way that does not change the functionaliy of my code.

Also, since my thread gets stopped in the onDestroy method, I guess my service stops as well. Is there any way to keep my service running even when my app has been closed?

Here's my code:

```
public class CounterService extends Service {
private Handler handler;
private int time = -1;
private boolean isActive;
private Intent timeBroadcaster;
private Runnable counter;
private Thread serviceCounter;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new Handler();
    timeBroadcaster = new Intent();
    timeBroadcaster.setAction("EXAMPLE_BROADCAST");
    counter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                isActive = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isInteractive();
                if (isActive) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    time += 1;
                } else {
                    if (time > 5) {
                        //log
                    }
                    time = 0;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
                timeBroadcaster.putExtra("counter", time);
                sendBroadcast(timeBroadcaster);
            }
    };

    serviceCounter = new Thread(counter);
    serviceCounter.start();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    //serviceCounter.interrupt();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to keep my service running even when my app has been closed?

you can use sync adapter which runs in background even app is stoped.
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html